# Why does Perl sub s require &

Tags: perl, compiler-errors, subroutine, reserved-words

The following file does not compile:

```
sub s {
    return 'foo';
}
sub foo {
    my $s = s();
    return $s if $s;
    return 'baz?';
}
```

The error from `perl -c` is:

```
syntax error at foobar.pl line 5 near "return"
  (Might be a runaway multi-line ;; string starting on line 3)
foobar.pl had compilation errors.
```

But if I replace `s()` with `&s()` it works fine. Can you explain why?

Comment: conflict with s/// substitution operator I would imagine

Comment: agreed, e.g. rename your sub to a() and it will complile

Comment: @PaulDixon, agreed, so that means that `m`, `y` and `q` are probably bad names for subs as well. Actually, I bet it compiles `m()` or `q()` without a complaint, but it just wouldn't do what you expect.

Comment: @Axeman, `m()` might give an uninitialised warning, but `q()` will indeed be silent.

Comment: @ikegami, yup, that's exactly what I got when trying them out. And `m()` always returns `1`, with the warning if `$_` is uninitialized.

Comment: As a side note - aside from a technical issue you are facing, you should consider ALWAYS 100% of time use **self-documenting identifiers**. Naming a sub "s" is a Very Bad Thing to do from software engineering standpoint, independently of Perl-specific technical issue you ran into.

Comment: @DVK, sub s is called so extremely often in our code, and it always has consistent usage throughout multiple projects that we manage, that we prefers shorter names. But you are probably right. It could certainly be a problem for new team members, especially because this is not the only short-hand named subroutine we have.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey - "Always code as if the person maintaining the code after you is a complete homicidal psychopath, and he knows where you live".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The & prefix definitively says you want to call your own function called "s", rather than any built-in with the same name. In this case, it's confusing it for a substitution operator (like `$stuff =~ s///;`, which can also be written `s()()`).

Here's [a PerlMonks discussion about what the ampersand does](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=428024).

Comment: You are right. When `sub s` and `$s` replaced to `sub t` and `$t` - there is no such fail

Comment: I realize this is probably just a simplified test case, but this might be an example of using more descriptive function names, too. They'll probably be less likely to be confused for something else.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have, as has already been pointed out, is that `s()` is interpreted as the `s///` substitution operator. Prefixing the function name with an ampersand is a workaround, although I would not say necessarily the correct one. In [perldoc perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html) the following is said about calling subroutines:

```
NAME(LIST);  # & is optional with parentheses.
NAME LIST;   # Parentheses optional if predeclared/imported.
&NAME(LIST); # Circumvent prototypes.
&NAME;       # Makes current @_ visible to called subroutine.
```

What the ampersand does here is merely to distinguish between the built-in function and your own.

The "proper" way to deal with this, apart from renaming your subroutine, is to realize what's going on under the surface. When you say

```
s();
```

What you are really saying is

```
CORE::s();
```

When what you mean is

```
main::s();
```

Comment: heh, didn't know `perl -e"CORE::s/a/b/"` worked. I'm not surprised; it just never occurred to me.

Comment: It feels rather weird, doesn't it. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 my $s = 's'->();
```

works too--oddly enough with `strict` on.

Comment: @TLP, Only works for a constant name, which is fine. On the other hand, `my $n = 's'; \&$n` also works under strict. That's not so fine.

Comment: @ikegami That is weird. `&$n` is caught by strict, but not when its made into a code reference. Almost sounds like a bug.

Comment: @TLP, Which means you can circumvent strict using `(\&$n)->()` instead of `$n->()`. More readable to use `no strict 'refs';`, though.

Comment: I've heard claims that that strict loophole is there to allow `&$AUTOLOAD`; dunno if that's actually true or just a rationalization.

Comment: @ysth, I can see that might be the case. And that might be to support the somewhat deprecated indirect method call. However, it would be nice to tune this with `strict` like `use strict -no_autoload => 1;` or `use strict -no_indirect => 1` and get a "stricter" strict--or even `use strict -absolutely_no_nonmethod_strings_as_subs => 1`. (I still like being able to use a string, from time to time and thus sort of gain the use the smalltalk-ish "object *message*" paradigm, instead of being locked into the C-ish quasi-vtable one.